# Combine response with JMeter when "Transfer-Encoding：chunked" is enabled

Tags: jmeter, httpresponse, chunked-encoding

I'm writing a performance test script in JMeter, but the site uses "Transfer-Encoding: chunked".

Is it possible to receive and combine all responses with JMeter?

I tried "prev.getResponseData ();" in JSR223 PostProcessor, but it seems that I can only get the last response.

Answer (score 0):

[JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) so it's just a matter of proper placement

[image]

As you can see

- `JSR223 PostProcessor 1` is applied only to `Sampler 1`
- and `JSR223 PostProcessor 2` is applied to all 3 Samplers

Comment: I'm sorry for my pool english. In my case, I have only one sampler in Test plan and this sampler's response has  "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" attribute.